# Display Preloader Icon - Until Page is Completely Loaded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How do I display a preloader until the page is completely loaded - instead of what I have?

I have 6 buttons on top of a page. Each button loads the same page but with different variables that are binded to an sql script that retrieves data. It takes a few seconds for this script to run and display info.

```
<div>
  <a href="page.php?t=1" class="button">button 1</a>
  <a href="page.php?t=2" class="button">button 2</a>
  <a href="page.php?t=3" class="button">button 3</a>
  <a href="page.php?t=4" class="button">button 4</a>
  <a href="page.php?t=5" class="button">button 5</a>
  <a href="page.php?t=6" class="button">button 6</a>
</div>

<div class="load"></div> <!-- display preloader icon -->
```

I have the following jquery that displays the preloader icon that will disappear in 20 seconds, but I really want it to disappear when the script is finished, the data has been displayed, and the page is completely loaded.

It works, but it is klugee - I think a better solution is to make it disappear without the 20 second delay.

```
<script>
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.load').addClass('loading');
        setTimeout(function () { 
           $('.load').removeClass('loading');
        }, 20000);
    });
</script>
```

And here is the relative CSS...

```
.loading {
    background: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    background-image: url('images/preloader.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 28px 32px;
}

.loading:after {
    content: "Loading data...";
    color: #CC0000;
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Does the button click do something else, e.g. load the href via Ajax? You should really attach the loading button to that, and then you can remove the loading class on the `complete` event. https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: Follow this link https://jsbin.com/huyusu/3/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: the button click loads the page - not with ajax - based on the button - different VARS are passed into the sql script for different data

Comment: You want a loader with a <a> link and not an ajax load. You can't because your page will refresh. Use ajax to load your page instead pure html and you will be able to handle loading event